# Не видит модуль. ImportError: No module named '_django'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-import

Когда запускажю `python3 manage.py makemigrations` , выдает в конце:

```
File ".../[name_project]/[name_project]/settings/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _django import *
ImportError: No module named '_django'
```

---

Структура:

```
[name_project]
├── [name_project]
│   ├── settings
│   |   ├── __init__.py
│   |   ├── _django.py
|   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
├── ...
│   ├── ...
│   ├── ...
└── manage.py
```

Файл `settings/__init__.py`:

```
from _django import *

try:
    from local import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

В файле `_django.py` находяться настройки проекта. Подскажите пожалуйста почему его не видно из файла `__init__.py`, почему не импортирует, может что то не дописал. PyCharm не ругается, он видит норм. Может у кого то было такое, подскажите. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А если `from [name_project].settings._django import *` ?

Comment: @andreymal так заработало) спасибо. а почему не хочет так как я написал?)

Comment: Особенности логики работы импорта в третьем питоне, но я так сходу точно не помню и нормальный ответ пока не оформлю

Comment: @andreymal понял. // тут пишут делать так как я https://goo.gl/28FxId

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы джанго импортировал модуль правильно, нужно явно указать ему путь от текущего модуля. В вашем случае это `from [name_project].settings._django import *`, как указал в комментарии @andreymal. Для импорта модулей есть два исключения: если импортируемая библиотека находится в той же директории, что и скрипт, в который вы её загружаете, либо если она находится в стандартном пути импорта модулей (например, в виртуальном окружении\Lib\site-packages), то путь можно не указывать. В [ссылке](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/rabota-s-modulyami-sozdanie-podklyuchenie-instrukciyami-import-i-from.html), которую вы привели, это описывается в разделе "Куда поместить модуль?":

> Пути поиска модулей указаны в переменной sys.path. В него включены
>   текущая директория, а также директории, в которых установлен python. Кроме
>   того, переменную sys.path можно изменять вручную, что позволяет
>   положить модуль в любое удобное для вас место (главное, не забыть в
>   главной программе модифицировать sys.path).